# oh-my-zsh error after upgrade: ~/.oh-my-zsh/lib/misc.zsh:3: parse error near `then'

Tags: shell, zsh, zshrc, oh-my-zsh

today I upgrade my oh-my-zsh and then start this error:

`` ~/.oh-my-zsh/lib/misc.zsh:3: parse error near `then' ``

Inside this file there is this shell loop...

```
## Load smart urls if available
for d in $fpath; do
    if [[ -e "$url/d-quote-magic"]]; then                                                                                                 
        autoload -U url-quote-magic
        zle -N self-insert url-quote-magic
    fi
done
```

I think the problem it's inside the if condition, but I don't have shell/zsh skills :(
Could anyone can help me with this?
Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: You need a space between the `"` and the `]]` in that `if` line.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use `upgrade_oh_my_zsh` upgrade to the latest version.

This issue fix [here](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/4047)

Comment: This is the real answer.

Answer (score 26):

Etan Reisner help me out with his commentary.

`You need a space between the " and the ]] in that if line.`

So I just add a space :') and fix the warning! :P

```
for d in $fpath; do
    if [[ -e "$url/d-quote-magic" ]]; then                                                                                                 
        autoload -U url-quote-magic
        zle -N self-insert url-quote-magic
    fi
done
```

Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 0):

According to their [Wiki on GitHub](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Design#customization) it is possible to overwrite internal `lib/*.zsh` files through creating a corresponding `$ZSH_CUSTOM/lib/*.zsh`:

> It's not documented in the *Customization* page, but `$ZSH_CUSTOM/lib/*.zsh` do override the corresponding internals lib files. If a custom one is present, it is sourced instead of the one in the distribution.